# How could you lower the risk of accepting zero confirmation transactions?

Tags: security, txpool, zero-confirmations

As far as I heard monero nodes don't add double spent tx to their txpool ([source](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/809/does-monero-use-replace-by-fee)), so if I connect to enough nodes it should be possible to lower the risk of a double spend attack right? (I could also cluster my control nodes if connection limitations would be a problem)

Via that logic it would also make sense to add nodes that are close or operated by mining pools.

What other options are there to also lower the risk?

I read [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/207/what-security-risks-are-associated-with-accepting-instant-transactions) but since monero does not have things like Replace by Fee it sounds to me less friendly to attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to more nodes increases the speed at which you will see a transaction double spending one you already have in your txpool, and thus mark this transaction as such. However, this is not foolproof since a miner does not have to relay a transaction for it to be mined.

Thus, this is risk based calculation, which should depend on things like the amount involved, whether a double spending tx was seen (since you don't know which one will get mined), how much recourse you have in case of actual double spend, the amount of time you wait for a possible double spend before acting on the tx, etc.